# Swagger ui express issue

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

My api not working on swaager and i dont know how to send parameters in reqeust in code
swaggerUi and swagger-jsdoc modules i am using

i want to send parameter in request how can i send i dont know

```
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "1.0.0",
      title: "users API",
      description: "users API Information",
      contact: {
        name: "abc.co"
      },
      servers: ["http://localhost:3000"]
    }
  },
  // ['.routes/*.js']
  apis: ["app/route/auth.js"]
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));



 // Routes
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/signIn:
 *  post:
 *    description: Sign In
 *    parameters:
 *      - name: email
 *        in: query
 *        description: Email of our user
 *        schema:
 *          type: string
 *          format: string
 *      - name: password
 *        in: query
 *        description: Password of  user
 *        schema:
 *          type: string
 *          format: string
 *    responses:
 *      '200':
 *        description: A successful response
 */
```

Comment: Do you mean sending values _in the request body_? Is your API definition `openapi: 3.0.0` or `swagger: '2.0'`?

Comment: `
"swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6", `

is my swagger version checked in package.json

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express this module